# PHP Array chunk get's accessed twice and I don't know why

Tags: php, arrays, loops, chunks

I wrote a function to start a tournament and people got Emails twice instead of once. So I tried to debug stuff. As you can see, I fill an array (part[]) with information from my database, shuffle it for the random enemy thing and then want to email the participants their opponents. I cut the whole email thing and just printed the array. But it gets printed twice. What makes me really sick is, that one of the prints appears above the

```
echo "<hr>";
```

which is crazy because there is no output.

```
function start_pre($t_id) {
   global $con;
    $participants=array();
    $sql = "SELECT u.name, u.btag, u.email FROM participant p, user u WHERE p.tournament_id = ".$t_id." AND p.user_id = u.user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $part[] = array(
                "name" => $row['name'], 
                "btag" => $row['btag'], 
                "email" => $row['email']
                );        
    }
    } else {echo "Problem.";}

    shuffle($part);
    echo "<hr>";

    $paare = array_chunk($part, 2);
    foreach ($paare as $paar) {

            print_r($paar);

    }

    $sql = "UPDATE tournament SET enrollable='0' WHERE tournament_id='".$t_id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    }
```

I cannot include a screenshot of the actual output because of privacy and stuff but I bet you can imagine how a printed array above and below a horizontal line look. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the output from `$row`? I mean, MySQL return twice?

Comment: Maybe your start_pre() function is called twice, that would explain the output above the <hr>.

Comment: I decided to change the print_r to a little iteration (echo $i, $i++) and I get the numbers twice. I don't call the function twice (checked that) and the mysql output is fine. :/

Comment: Make sure about your MySql result set have single time values!

Comment: Side note: make sure to escape `$t_id` before passing it into a query, or use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be calling the whole function twice. Also, It would perform better if you just use `order by rand()` in mysql rather than `shuffle`.

Comment: No sorry it is called once, "if (isset($_POST['quali_submit'])) {
        start_pre($_POST['t_id']);
    }" - which is kinda straight forward. This is the only part in the code where  the function is called. Oh and btw thank you for your advice. Gonna consider that.

Comment: yep, only in the function, but well i just saw that this is also doubled

Comment: Oh my god nevermind. I copied the function to the top of the page instead of cutting it. It was called twice. Sorry for your time but also thank you.